# Cloudbreak Advantages and Limitations

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, cloudbreak

I have gone through the cloudbreak documentation and I am still not sure what is the exact purpose of this component.

Is it actually useful only for deploying the cluster in any cloud services and if so can we customise the components that needs to be installed in the cluster.

If it is only for maintaining the deployment of a cluster then is there any cost involved in using cloudbreak?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudbreak main purpose is Hdp or Hdf cluster management. It provides an UI and api to access, create and edit the cluster. It also provides access control management for the clusters. Yes you can customize the components installation via ambari blueprint. 
One additional benefit was from its component periscope, which provides autoscaling based on ambari alerts.